# Refer to ID (as selector) that is already inside HTML link tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a link that is generated by a core module (meaning I can't modify the code) as such:

```
<a id="my-unique-id-1" class="my-link-class" href="/switch off">Switch off</a>
```

Problem is, the ID and class are within the `<a>` tag and I do not have any useable elements wrapped around the link that I can use.

When clicked, it goes and do what it has to do server side (see code following), and then returns this:

```
<a id="my-unique-id-1" class="my-link-class it-is-off" href="/switch on">Switch on</a>
```

I want to replace or amend the complete first link.

First the jQuery script:

```
$(".my-link-class").click(function() {
  var current_id = $(this).attr('id');
  var link = $(this).attr('href');

  $.ajax({url: link, success: function (result) {
  //All works fine up to here. The changes are made in server side and returns the new link as the result. 
//Following is my problem:

    if(result){ 
      $(current_id).replaceWith(result); //the selector is wrong, I know.
    }
  }
}
```

My problem is that the id (current_id) is already within a `<a>` tag.
How can I refer to the selector in the tag.
I tried:

```
$(current_id).replaceWith(result); //nothing happens
$('#' + current_id).replaceWith(result);
$('a#' + current_id).replaceWith(result);
```

But I get with the last two TypeError: Argument 1 of Node.appendChild does not implement interface Node.

(I know I can do other things than replaceWith such as changing text and href in link, but the problem here is to find the selector first).

Comment: `$(a.my-link-class)` is incorrect syntactically.  Is that just because it's example code?

Comment: You can possibly fetch them with their hrefs, like `$('[href="/switch off"]')`

Comment: Typo fixed $(".my-link-class")

Comment: @Ted there are many links on the page. I have to work with the unique ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `$(this).replaceWith()`:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.my-link-class', function() {
  var html = '<a id="my-unique-id-1" class="my-link-class it-is-off" href="/switch on">Switch on</a>';
  $(this).replaceWith(html);
  return false;
});
```

```css
.it-is-off {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="my-unique-id-1" class="my-link-class" href="/switch off">Switch off</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two things happening here.

1. You are trying to use an ID to replace an element, when it would be easier to just keep a reference to the DOM element you want to replace rather than finding it twice.
2. You are binding an event to an anchor tag that you are then trying to replace. Once you replace it, the event will go away. The way to avoid this issue is bind your event to something that won't be changing. That can be the element right above the one you are going to replace, or it can be a much higher up element like the `body` element.

Here's a possible solution that fixes both problems. I've written a function called `simulatedAjax` to give an idea of what I think you're saying the backend code is doing. It follows the same idea as the jQuery $.get using the `configurationObject, callback(result)` signature.

```
function simulatedAjax(config, done){
  var onOffText = (config.url === "on" ? "off" : "on");

  done('<a href="'+onOffText+'" id="custom-thing" class="custom-link">Switch '+ onOffText +'</a>');

}
```

And now your client code

```
$(function(){

  // Bind the click to the body element, but with a delegate to your link class .custom-link
  $('body').on('click', '.custom-link', function(e){

     // Store a reference to the A tag, name is irrelevant but self is easy to understand
     var self = this;

     // Keep the page from actually navigating to the href
      e.preventDefault();

      //Replace with real jQuery $.get or $.ajax with configuration
      simulatedAjax({
          url: $(this).attr('href')
      }, function(resultHTML){

          // Since we stored a reference to the original in the self variable, we can just replace it here. Note that if we tried to use `this` here, it wouldn't refer to the right `this`
          $(self).replaceWith(resultHTML);
      });
  });
});
```

You can see this code sample working in this JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/x83vfmuw/

Hope this helps!